# Jenkins: прерывание выполнения дочерних проектов

Tags: jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Добрый день.

Я использую Jenkins. Есть проект (**multijob**), который вызывает некоторые дочерние работы (**jobs**). Я могу прерывать выполнение этого проекта (как собственноручно, так и по таймауту, используя **Build-timeout**). Тем не менее, дочерние работы, запущенные текущей, не прекращают своё выполнение даже в случае прерывания выполнения родительской.

Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы при вынужденном останове работы multijob'а прекращались и job'ы, выполнение которых было инициировано?

Спасибо за помощь.